# Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect

Tags: php, session, yii, session-variables, unset

Iam trying to remove an element from session array in Yii using the following code.

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
        $arraylen = count($session['the_variable']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $arraylen; $i++)
        {
            if ($session['the_variable'][$i] == $providerId)
            {
                unset($session['the_variable'][$i]);
            }
        }
```

But it is showing the error

> Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect

I tried using `array_splice($session['the_variable'],$i,$i-1);`  instead of unset . Then also it is showing the same error.  Is there any method to remove an element from the session array?.Iam using 2 different controller actions to insert into the session array and delete element from session array. 
 To insert Iam using the code

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
        if (!isset($session['the_variable']) || count($session['the_variable']) == 0)
        {
            $session['the_variable'] = array($providerId);
        } else
        {
            $myarr = $session['the_variable'];
            $myarr[] = $providerId;
            $session['the_variable'] = $myarr;
        }
        array('session' => $session);
```

Insertion is working well , but deletion is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> $vars = &$session['the_variable'];
>   ...
>   unset($vars[$i])
>   ...

$session is object, not array. `$session['the_variable']` is overload `$session->get('the_variable')` (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#get-detail)

Or, maybe, you need to get array from session, change it and resave...

Answer (score 2):

```
    $session = Yii::app()->session;
    $vars = $session['the_variable'];
    $arraylen = count($vars);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $arraylen; $i++)
    {
        if ($vars[$i] == $providerId)
        {
            unset($vars[$i]);
        }
    }
    $vars = array_values($vars);
    $session['the_variable'] = $vars;
```

Now it is working well .. Thanks for your reply.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yii has a built-in mechanism to handle this cleanly. Keep to the conventions and follow the correct practice:

```
Yii::app()->session->remove('the_variable');
or
$session = Yii::app()->session;
$session->remove('the_variable');
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant unset a multi dimensional array session by unset like that, I dont know why , but try this (I also simplified your code) :

```
        $session = Yii::app()->session;
        $key = array_search($providerId,$session['the_variable']);
        $session->remove($key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy stuff:

```
Yii::app()->session->remove('the_variable');
or
$session = Yii::app()->session;
$session->remove('the_variable');
```